# How to get a file that it is inside my jar file?

Tags: java, file, jar, getresource

I need to access to a xsd file that it's inside my jar. My problem is that my classpath is  `C:\Users\fabio\Documents`.

My jar file it's in that path too , so how can I get the file that I need?

I tried  `File xsdFile=new File(String.valueOf(MigrationsApplication.class.getResource("DBRegister.xsd")));` but got this error message  `schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/C:/Users/fabio/Documents/null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.`

This is my location of the xsd file I need
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> `MigrationsApplication.class.getResource("DBRegister.xsd")`

This part is good.

> `new File`

Nope. File refers to an *actual file on your harddisk*. And that resource aint one of those. You can't use File here. Period.

There are only two APIs that read resources:

- Ones that work with `InputStream` or some other abstracted source concept such as `URL`. Perhaps in addition (with e.g. overloaded methods) to ones that take in a `File`, `Path` or (bad design) `String` representing a file path.
- Crap ones you shouldn't be using.

Let's hope you have the first kind of API :)

Then we fix some bugs:

1. Use `getResourceAsStream` to get an InputStream, `getResource` to get a URL. Which one should you use? Well, check the API of where you're passing this resource to. For example, swing's `ImageIcon` accepts URLs, so you'd use `getResource` there.
2. `.getResource("DBRegister.xsd")` looks for that file in the same place `MigrationsApplication.class` is located. Which is the wrong path! Your `DBRegister.xsd` is in the 'root'. Include a slash at the start to resolve relative to root.

Easy enough to take care of it:

```
try (var in = MigrationsApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/DBRegister.xsd")) {
   whateverYouArePassingThatFileTo(in);
}
```

If `whateverYouArePassingThatFileTo()` doesn't have a variant that takes in an `InputStream`, delete that library and find a better one.

Comment: Since the resource is an XSD, I suspect he’ll want to pass the resource URL to [SchemaFactory.newSchema(URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema(java.net.URL)), as in: SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(MigrationsApplication.class.getResource("/DBRegister.xsd"))